# Transfer cell service from one iPhone 4 to another

Tags: iphone

I just bought a 32 GB iPhone 4 on eBay to replace my broken iPhone 4. How do I change my Verizon service from one to the other?

Answer (score 2):

Take it into a Verizon store and an employee should be able to help you.